# Using linq c# how can I select using a condition two different lists

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Here are my DataModels:

```
public class GeneratedAlertDataModel : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// the alert that will be generated 
    /// from configuration of alert
    /// </summary>
    public string AlertText { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public AlertDataModel Alert { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}

public class AlertDataModel : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public PriorityLevel PriorityLevel { get; set; }

    public bool ShowOldAlerts { get; set; }
}
```

**The relation between the two tables in many to one, an Alert have multiple generatedAlerts.**

I have two cases:

1. Is to retreive a list of generated alert where read = true, if the property ShowOldAlerts in alert is set to false.
2. Is to retreive all the alerts if the property ShowOldAlerts in Alert is set to true.
   But I have to return the all this is one list.

I have tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
        var generatedAlertDbQuery = _context.GeneratedAlerts.Include(a => a.Alert)
            // if set ShowAlert to false, get only the not viewed generated alerts
            .Where(a => a.Alert.ShowOldAlerts).Select(a => a)
            // if set ShowAlert to true, get only the not viewed generated alerts
            .Where(a => !a.Alert.ShowOldAlerts).Select(a => a).Where(a => !a.Read)

            .OrderBy(a => a.ReceivedDate) // Ordered by the receive date
            .Take(take) // Taking maximum (will be configured in client)
            .AsQueryable();

        var generatedAlertResponse = await generatedAlertDbQuery.Select(a => new GeneratedAlertResponse
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Alert = _mapper.Map<AlertInfoResponse>(a.Alert),
            ReceivedDate = a.ReceivedDate,
            Completed = a.Completed,
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question... How are two entities related? You have a list of `Alert` objects; some may have property as true; others as false. How do these values affect whether you choose *all* or *some* generated alerts?

Comment: The relation is many to one, the alerts have multiple generatedAlerts, so basically the alert class is a configuration to generate multiple alerts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this.

Filtere where

- `x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts == true`

  or
- `x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts == false && Read == false`

**Example**

```
var results = _context.GeneratedAlerts
    .Include(a => a.Alert)
    .Where(x => x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts || !x.Read)
    .Select(a => new GeneratedAlertResponse
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Alert = _mapper.Map<AlertInfoResponse>(a.Alert),
        ReceivedDate = a.ReceivedDate,
        Completed = a.Completed
        ...
    }.ToList();
```

If you need the results separated, it's probably best to still keep the one query (one round trip to the database), however you can filter the results after the fact.

```
var alerts = results.Where(x => x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts);

var read = results.Axcept(alerts );
```

Comment: If I have to filter where:
`x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts == true` (get all lists)
and if `x.Alert.ShowOldAlerts == false && Read == false`

Comment: @Hasagiii updated... Do you need this in 2 separate results ?

Comment: Yes, excatelly.

Comment: can u tell me exactelly what do u mean by seperatelly ?

Comment: @Hasagiii how about we spin this around. Have you run the code, does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228331/discussion-between-hasagiii-and-00110001).

Answer (score 0):

For the first case which retrieves generated alerts if `Read` is true and `ShowOldAlerts` is false. If I understood the question correctly, this should work.

```
var alerts = _context.GeneratedAlerts
    .Where(c => c.Read && !c.Alert.ShowOldAlerts);
```

For the second case where you only retrieve the generated alerts only if `ShowOldAlerts` is false.

```
var alerts = _context.GeneratedAlerts
         .Where(c => c.Alert.ShowOldAlerts);
```

To return as one list, the conditions seem awkward, but here it is

```
var alerts = _context.GeneratedAlerts
    .Where(c => (c.Read && !c.Alert.ShowOldAlerts) || c.Alert.ShowOldAlerts);
```

Comment: Should I concatenate them both ?

Comment: @Hasagiii I do not understand what you mean by concatenate.

Comment: I mean returning them as one list

Comment: Thanks it worked, it was all about the logic